# When do curly braces disappear in macro definitions? (e.g. \documentclass expansion)

Tags: tex-core, expansion, grouping, latex-base, documentclass

I've been looking into how `\documentclass` and friends are actually defined, and I noticed something peculiar which I'd like to understand.

Let's say I have `\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{article}`. From what I gather, `\documentclass` ultimately expands to `\@fileswith@ptions\@clsextension`, which is defined thus:

```
  \@ifnextchar[
  {\@fileswith@pti@ns#1[{#2}]#3}%
  {\@fileswith@pti@ns#1[{#2}]#3[]}}
```

I gather from that, that the optional parameters `11pt, titlepage` are now put in braces. From simple experiments of the form `\edef\foo{{{\bar}}}`, it seems that those braces are not magically removed somehow, i.e. they seem to be preserved in further expansions, even when using `\edef` - i.e. from all I can gather the expansion is:

`\@fileswith@pti@ns\@clsextension[{11pt,titlepage}]article[]`.

- First confusion: `\@fileswith@pti@ns` contains the line `\xdef\@classoptionslist{\zap@space#2 \@empty}`, which it seems to me is intended to remove the space between `11pt,` and `titlepage`. But since `\@fileswith@ptions` put the optional parameters in braces, that shouldn't have any effect. In deed, trying `\zap@space {a  b} c \@empty` yields `a bc` rather than `abc`.
- Furthermore, `\@fileswith@pti@ns` ultimately does `\@onefilewithoptions#3[{#2}][{#4}]#1` - meaning it puts an *additional* pair of braces around the optional parameters, yielding

  `\@onefilewithoptions article[{{11pt, titlepage}}][{}]\@clsextension`. So now we have *two* spurious pairs of braces around the package parameters.

But all the further processing of the parameters is (ultimately) based on for-loops and `\@in`s, which split at commas (using parameter strings with comma-delimiters). So it seems to me that the braces that are introduced by `\@fileswith@ptions` and `\@fileswith@pti@ns` have to either be removed somewhere, or in *some* places they are ignored...? Can someone explain TeXs magic behavior here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX drops the braces from a macro argument if the entire argument is in a brace group so in

`\frac{1}{2}`

`#1` is `1` not `{1}`

But this also applies to delimited arguments after

`\def\foo[#1]#2{....}`

then in `\foo[{abc}]{xyz}`  `#1` is `abc` and `#2` is `xyz`  both brace groups are dropped.

the code you quote does `[{#2}]`   in case `#2` contains a `]` in which case the delimited argument matching would fail, but the braces surround the entire argument so are never passed on to the macro being called.

Comment: great, thank you :)